# how to Autofill my data in java program

Tags: java, windows, swing, jdbc, autocomplete

Hello people,
             I just learned java & it's basics. I really new to programming. I'm really ambitious to create my first project.  My Application kind of used for  ** grocery store** type. Please Understand.(I couldn't explain it) 
Details:

- It's just kind of Seller ledger book
- It has all types of products prices & their other important details & which is updatable
- It's design kind of Ms-Excel where default columns are generated
- when a item is typed in respective column  in the product name. The application retrieves that particular item & it fills in the details. ( main feature)

I'm sorry for very vague details.Well my take is

- Java Swings for GU-Interface
- I think I need database for my application

I clearly don't have enough knowledge but trying to implement this project only way I can motivate my self to learn. Internet is my only resource. Please Help me.. in anyway.. Thank you.

Comment: [Creating a GUI with Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html); [JDBC Basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are new to programming, I would suggest create a CSV file and put details in there. When you start your program you can read the details from there. The format of File could be like:

```
ProductId,ProductName,Price,Description
P1,Soap,10,Cleaning
P2,Shampoo,50,Hair Wash
.....
```

and so on.
You will easily find ways to read a CSV file as in this link.
[Here](http://www.java67.com/2015/08/how-to-load-data-from-csv-file-in-java.html)

Comment: Adding to Akshaya's response, if you want to extend your project to support multiple ways to autofill/suggestions based on various fields such as Name,Type etc. You can use Embedded databases in java and use sql queries to load suggestions  
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javadb-141163.html

Comment: Thank you so much for .suggesting